# Build Fails Entity Framework - Compilation Error

Tags: entity-framework, tfs, entity-framework-6, tfsbuild, c#-6.0

I have installed entity framework v 6.0.0.0 nuget package.

When building solution locally, it works great without any issues. But, when I check in the code and when the build runs on server, it throws below compilation error.

`Primary reference "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.`

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: reinstall the entity framework nuget package.

Comment: I tried this many times. Doesn't seem to work. This was the solution provided in many forums.

Comment: hmm weird indeed. is this application or web project? can check app.config (web.config for website based project)? if there some unnecessary bindings..

Answer (score 3):

The problem you probably have is that your build agent isn't fetching the Nuget package for you.

In my company this is caused by the service account that the build agent is running under not having the corporate proxy set by default.

So firstly you need to run the build agent service as a real user (i.e. not Network Service or Local Service). Then you need to log in to the build agent as that user and set the proxy by hand. Hopefully you can use your own proxy settings.

It's been a long time since I did this, but I also seem to remember that there might be some Visual Studio setting that is off by default about Nuget package restore. So what I generally do when I'm troubleshooting this kind of thing is try to build the solution as the build agent user on the build agent from within Visual Studio. Once you can do that successfully the build should work. It should also work as you add Nuget packages.

If this completely fails to work because you can't get the build agent user through the proxy then you can always create a local Nuget file share and copy the packages to that share, then add the share to your Nuget config. This is configured in the `nuget.config` file. Mine looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="Private package source" value="\\BuildController\nuget\Packages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

The second package source is a file share where we put our own packages.

Comment: thanks. But, I have never build the solution as the build agent user on the build agent from within Visual Studio. Just hearing for the first time. Can you elaborate on that so that I can google that in detail.

Comment: You need to find out which account the build agent runs as and then you will need to log into the build agent as that user via remote desktop (or directly if it is a physical machine). Did you set up the build agent yourself?

Comment: Nope, DevOps take care of build agent and all.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that you work with them to sort this out. The build isn't restoring the Nuget packages during the build and that is why the build is failing. To troubleshoot why you need to get onto the build agent and try to build the solution in Visual Studio as the build agent user. Once that works, the build will almost certainly work.

Comment: It seems build template has something that was pointing to c# older version. When template was upgraded to c# v6, the build succeeded. But @Briantyler , I would like to know how to replicate the issue when you build it locally like is there a way to catch this before it is checked in to the server. Would really appreciate that. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, the only way to test the build is to run one. It's basically an exercise in trial and error that gets somewhat easier with experience, I guess that error was thrown by another part of the build (like getting a version number or something) not the actual MS build step.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a rookie when it comes to build server. Would you suggest some articles/websites to understand step wise process of MSBuilds?

Comment: This would be the place: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx

Comment: Thanks a tonne for all your help. No more questions :-)

Comment: Seems like our build template was pointing to older version of c# lesser than version 6. When we got out template updated to c# version 6, everything seems to be working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the versions are not updated properly , Uninstall and reinstall entity framework from Nuget Package Manager and make sure that package.config and web.config has the same version that's present in your reference / bin .